# XML standards for financial SOAP-based web-services

Tags: web-services, soap, financial

I'm developing an XSD scheme for SOAP-based web-service that provides financial calculations. Service response contains historical performance of portfolios of investments and different measures: rates of returns, standard deviations etc.

I'd like to know if there are some well known standards for such information? For example:

- how many decimal digits should values have;
- how currency/percentage/date/etc values are formatted in SOAP response;
- any standard enumerations for data types;
- any standard structures.

Do you follow any internal standards in your web-services? Can you suggest anything?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at a standard called XBRL

Comment: Can I use XBRL to create my own taxonomies? Can I use some XBRL tags for the numbers provided in my reports? For example, is there any standard tags for Sharpe Ration or Annualized Return?

Answer (score 1):

At one point I bumped into a standard called [IFX](http://www.ifxforum.org/standards/standard_overview_2010-06-01/). Haven't personally used it, but it was supposed to be specifically designed for interoperability of systems seeking to exchange financial information. There were also some developments made to [allow IFX documents transmission using web services](http://www.ifxforum.org/standards/wswg).

See if it helps in any way.